# Prove: when $0<p<1$, $\int_E f^p d\mu \leq \mu(E)^{1-p}$?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $\mu$ is a positive measure on $X$ and $f: X \to (0, \infty)$ is a measurable function satisfying $\int_X f d\mu=1$. Prove, for every $E \subset X$ with $0 <\mu (E) < \infty$, that $\int_E (\log f) d\mu \leq \mu (E) \log \frac{1}{\mu(E)} $ and, when $0<p<1$, $\int_E f^p d\mu \leq \mu(E)^{1-p}$.

Any hint to get me going will be appreciated.

By the hint of a comment, I use $\phi (x)=-x^p$, which is convex on (0,1). Since its second derivative is greater than 0. Then I use Jensen's inequality, I can get this

$$(\int_X f d\mu)^p \geq \int_X f^p d\mu$$

What next?

Comment: Perhaps Jensen's inequality. For example $\phi(x)=x^p$ is concave on $[0,\infty)$ for $0<p<1$.

Comment: @OliverDíaz But Jensen's inequality is applied in convex function?

Comment: and so, to $-\phi$ for any concave function $\phi$ (why?)

Comment: @OliverDíaz Yes, the function $-x^p$ is convex, since its second derivative is greater than 0. But what next?

Comment: Notice that if $\mu(E)>0$,  the function $\nu_E:=A\mapsto \frac{1}{m(E)}m(A\cap E)$ is a probability function. What you have is of the form $\int \phi(f) d\nu_E$ with $\phi$ concave ($-\phi$ convex).

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. I write down something in my updated edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll focus on the second inequality (and re-route back to the first in an update later). Let $q \in (1, \infty)$. Then we have
\begin{align*}
1 &= \int_{X} f d\mu \\
&\ge \int_E f \mathbf{1}_E d\mu \\
&\ge \left(\int_E f^{1/q} d\mu\right)^q\left(\int_E \mathbf{1}_E^{-\frac{1}{q-1}} d\mu\right)^{-(q-1)} && \text{Reverse Holder inequality}\\
&= \left(\int_E f^{1/q} d\mu\right)^q\mu(E)^{-(q-1)}
\end{align*}
or $\int_E f^{1/q} d\mu \le \mu(E)^{1 - \frac{1}{q}}$. Let $q = 1/p$ for our desired result.

Comment: @OliverDíaz  Not another word from me!

Comment: sorry if my previous comment came out strong. I was just trying to state that the reverse Holder inequality, though easy to obtained, may not be a common result given. Friendly criticism that all :)

Comment: Thank you. Can you also show the proof of the first inequality? or give me some hints? any relationship between 2 inequalities?

Comment: I understand your proof. But I still don't have idea to finish the 1st inequality.